# How do I integrate a line created by the smooth.spline function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to integrate a list created by predict(smooth.spline) but I'm getting the following error: Error in stats::integrate(...) :
evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length.

predict(smooth.spline(x,y) gives:

```
$x
  [1]  0.000  0.033  0.067  0.100  0.133  0.167  0.200  0.233  0.267  0.300  0.333  0.367  0.400  0.433  0.467  0.500
 [17]  0.533  0.567  0.600  0.633  0.667  0.700  0.733  0.767  0.800  0.833  0.867  0.900  0.933  0.967  1.000  1.033
 [33]  1.067  1.100  1.133  1.167  1.200  1.233  1.267  1.300  1.333  1.367  1.400  1.433  1.467  1.500  1.533  1.567
 [49]  1.600  1.633  1.667  1.700  1.733  1.767  1.800  1.833  1.867  1.900  1.933  1.967  2.000  2.033  2.067  2.100
 [65]  2.133  2.167  2.200  2.233  2.267  2.300  2.333  2.367  2.400  2.433  2.467  2.500  2.533  2.567  2.600  2.633
 [81]  2.667  2.700  2.733  2.767  2.800  2.833  2.867  2.900  2.933  2.967  3.000  3.033  3.067  3.100  3.133  3.167
 [97]  3.200  3.233  3.267  3.300  3.333  3.367  3.400  3.433  3.467  3.500  3.533  3.567  3.600  3.633  3.667  3.700
[113]  3.733  3.767  3.800  3.833  3.867  3.900  3.933  3.967  4.000  4.033  4.067  4.100  4.133  4.167  4.200  4.233
[129]  4.267  4.300  4.333  4.367  4.400  4.433  4.467  4.500  4.533  4.567  4.600  4.633  4.667  4.700  4.733  4.767
[145]  4.800  4.833  4.867  4.900  4.933  4.967  5.000  5.033  5.067  5.100  5.133  5.167  5.200  5.233  5.267  5.300
[161]  5.333  5.367  5.400  5.433  5.467  5.500  5.533  5.567  5.600  5.633  5.667  5.700  5.733  5.767  5.800  5.833
[177]  5.867  5.900  5.933  5.967  6.000  6.033  6.067  6.100  6.133  6.167  6.200  6.233  6.267  6.300  6.333  6.367
[193]  6.400  6.433  6.467  6.500  6.533  6.567  6.600  6.633  6.667  6.700  6.733  6.767  6.800  6.833  6.867  6.900
[209]  6.933  6.967  7.000  7.033  7.067  7.100  7.133  7.167  7.200  7.233  7.267  7.300  7.333  7.367  7.400  7.433
[225]  7.467  7.500  7.533  7.567  7.600  7.633  7.667  7.700  7.733  7.767  7.800  7.833  7.867  7.900  7.933  7.967
[241]  8.000  8.033  8.067  8.100  8.133  8.167  8.200  8.233  8.267  8.300  8.333  8.367  8.400  8.433  8.467  8.500
[257]  8.533  8.567  8.600  8.633  8.667  8.700  8.733  8.767  8.800  8.833  8.867  8.900  8.933  8.967  9.000  9.033
[273]  9.067  9.100  9.133  9.167  9.200  9.233  9.267  9.300  9.333  9.367  9.400  9.433  9.467  9.500  9.533  9.567
[289]  9.600  9.633  9.667  9.700  9.733  9.767  9.800  9.833  9.867  9.900  9.933  9.967 10.000 10.033 10.067 10.100

$y
  [1]   59.96571  182.14589  308.06545  430.28967  552.13181  676.76001  796.27007  913.45605 1030.73901 1140.24735
 [11] 1244.62019 1345.89199 1437.37738 1521.99577 1601.97896 1672.60118 1736.28174 1794.58753 1844.06630 1886.59891
 [21] 1923.24013 1952.04715 1974.93273 1993.22884 2006.84446 2017.75964 2027.59482 2036.61631 2045.82650 2056.14890
 [31] 2067.21217 2079.44489 2093.29127 2107.48046 2121.84443 2136.20938 2149.03007 2160.03152 2168.83055 2174.72156
 [41] 2177.92034 2178.50434 2177.25261 2175.18231 2173.05271 2171.23280 2169.75413 2168.60865 2167.58021 2166.28136
 [51] 2164.31765 2161.56924 2157.84126 2153.06845 2147.68110 2141.80856 2135.99289 2131.40947 2128.57716 2127.73980
 [61] 2129.07173 2132.52768 2137.84677 2144.15311 2151.04004 2158.20845 2164.72665 2170.38182 2175.16221 2178.72060
 [71] 2181.26140 2183.34329 2185.47108 2188.20964 2191.71999 2195.72978 2200.17822 2204.67512 2208.37304 2210.99201
 [81] 2212.16148 2211.52661 2209.27941 2205.52709 2200.82773 2195.80333 2191.14046 2187.86227 2186.22909 2186.61490
 [91] 2189.21504 2193.74033 2200.00587 2207.23478 2215.15186 2223.55507 2231.56558 2239.35648 2247.15616 2254.58452
[101] 2262.25845 2270.90839 2280.40791 2291.00929 2302.93232 2315.07098 2327.30700 2339.53707 2350.58890 2360.39110
[111] 2368.83106 2375.48715 2380.80457 2385.21836 2389.36786 2394.40853 2401.47143 2410.55245 2422.11132 2436.78865
[121] 2453.43711 2472.06315 2492.92121 2514.41941 2536.79884 2560.48574 2584.09299 2608.55242 2635.61496 2664.80169
[131] 2697.76567 2735.79016 2776.54744 2820.81417 2868.96931 2916.89215 2964.73344 3012.72300 3056.87880 3097.62601
[141] 3135.48071 3167.79172 3195.56342 3220.27772 3241.55129 3261.03300 3279.41808 3295.63106 3310.16876 3323.00826
[151] 3332.94381 3340.03845 3344.39672 3345.94806 3345.34005 3343.03700 3339.80326 3336.46397 3333.90149 3333.10272
[161] 3334.29421 3337.81087 3343.53943 3351.20699 3360.65966 3370.86645 3381.56693 3392.54603 3402.66565 3411.98625
[171] 3420.52889 3427.65472 3433.82738 3439.48350 3444.52521 3449.15602 3453.47469 3457.18103 3460.26646 3462.61691
[181] 3463.90801 3464.03740 3462.81764 3460.39884 3456.89191 3452.34917 3447.51817 3442.81170 3438.49642 3434.61442
[191] 3430.68032 3426.12851 3420.51956 3412.97424 3402.44270 3389.08015 3372.22571 3350.92543 3326.65679 3299.18832
[201] 3267.98034 3235.60437 3201.97284 3166.74241 3132.31425 3097.84231 3062.28419 3027.69000 2992.94842 2956.82062
[211] 2921.23160 2884.94573 2846.71167 2808.67879 2769.66061 2728.44573 2687.49711 2645.56586 2600.90609 2555.63728
[221] 2507.95605 2455.68553 2401.27869 2342.78231 2278.34602 2212.01091 2142.26985 2067.55831 1993.06085 1917.46648
[231] 1839.35164 1764.18963 1690.48889 1616.92292 1548.58020 1483.78349 1421.22958 1365.02723 1313.47540 1265.38224
[241] 1223.67578 1186.75059 1153.52704 1125.77912 1102.26304 1082.24588 1066.67248 1054.56916 1045.35940 1039.20608
[251] 1035.34023 1033.24970 1032.58511 1032.85175 1033.69725 1034.73437 1035.66522 1036.21146 1036.16962 1035.42480
[261] 1033.76896 1031.12350 1027.27529 1021.86005 1014.99372 1006.33762  995.34857  982.53272  967.47341  949.51507
[271]  929.75179  907.75896  882.86053  856.68919  828.72692  798.22411  767.10143  734.59731  699.82246  665.13042
[281]  629.85926  593.30425  558.00149  523.24723  488.37898  455.79640  424.78607  394.77350  367.79586  343.17422
[291]  320.38235  300.83710  283.85695  268.87085  256.54269  246.16897  237.22002  229.91066  223.66652  218.11256
[301]  213.36419  209.04868  204.88159  200.94805

smooth <- predict(smooth.spline(x,y))
```

Then I pass this data to the function command:

```
func <- function(x) smooth
#Attempt to integrate
integrate(func,0,10)$value
Error in stats::integrate(...) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

I get the same error when I attempt to Vectorize the function

```
> integrate(Vectorize(func),0,10)$value
Error in stats::integrate(...) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to find an upper limit to the integral with a given Area under the curve but I can't even seem to complete the integral function.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any reproducible data, so I can't test this advice for you, but here are two suggestions.

First:  if you are starting with the `smooth` object that has evenly spaced `x` values and corresponding `y` values from predictions from the spline, then don't bother with `integrate()`, just use the trapezoidal rule to approximate the integral:

```
with(smooth, (x[2]-x[1])*(sum(y) - mean(y[c(1, length(y))])))
```

The Simpson's rule formula would be a bit more accurate but also more complicated.

Second:  if you are starting with data vectors `x` and `y`, then you should construct a function which takes a vector of new `x` values and returns the corresponding predictions of `y`, and pass that function to `integrate()`.  Here I do it that way:

```
fit <- smooth.spline(x, y)
smooth <- function(x) predict(fit, x)$y
integrate(smooth, 0, 10)
```